# Pagination with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am looking for a **CLEAN** example that explains how pagination is done using thymeleaf and spring boot.

There are a lot of examples out there, but they are not complete.

I am actually looking for an example that implements **pagination blocks** as well. For example, if the total pages is 150, I would like the pages to show in blocks as in **<< 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5... >>**, when you click the arrows, the next block of pages would show as **<< 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10... >>**

Thank you

Comment: Pagination is done on the database and paginator is collection of links with proper query parameters. Use PageRequest object

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain the difference between PageRequest object and Page in spring boot?

Comment: Well page request is what you want to get, eg page number, hits on page count while Page is what you actually got - page number, total results, results on page (can be less then waht you expeced) pages count - all the good stuf you need to build paginator.

Comment: And what is the most important, PageRequest implements Pageable and this can be provided as an argument directly to Spring Data Repositories for instant database pagination handling. I forgot to mention that Page holds actual results, not only metadata

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a simple solution using Java math methods: Math.max and Math.min as follows:

```
    int current = page.getNumber() + 3;
    int begin = Math.max(1, current - 5);
    int end = Math.min(begin + 6, page.getTotalPages());
```

I then passed these variables to thymeleaf #numbers.sequence as in:

```
                <li class="page-item"
                th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(beginIndex, endIndex)} ">

                <a th:href="@{/jobs(p=${i})}" th:text="${i}" class="nav-link"
                th:classappend="${currentPage}==${i}?'activepagenumber':''"></a>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Issmeil B. answer, just in case if you want to calculate the start and end index on the page, you can call the static class in the Math class. Eg

```
<div class="paginate-pagination"
     th:with="current=${page.number + 3},
     beginIndex=${T(java.lang.Math).max(0,current-5)},
     endIndex=${T(java.lang.Math).min(begin + 6 , page.totalPages-1)}">

    ....

</div>
```

Comment: Not bad; but, it's probably cleaner to calculate the indices on the controller and insert them in the model map